# Make glutMouseFunc() be called first than the one glutDisplayFunc() in C++ OpenGL

Tags: c++, glut

I have this inside my main loop:

```
init ();
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
glutMainLoop();
```

What I'm trying to do is an OpenGL program that relies on mouse clicks for updating the values of certain variables in the program and then displaying the results of other functions that rely on these. However, whenever OpenGL detects a mouse click it goes on to the display function first and updates the canvas and then goes into the mouse function. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: OpenGL is doing nothing there. OpenGL just draws things. What you're dealing with here is GLUT. Also this **is not** your main loop. The main loop is somewhere inside GLUT and you enter it by calling `glutMainLoop`. The order of the `glut…Func` calls does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `mouse` call `glutPostRedisplay()` which will cause `display` to be called again.